# QStyledItemDelegate: how do I make it replace the current data and not just be on top of it?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm pretty new to Python and PyQT5, so forgive me if there is a very simple answer to this question! I have tried to find an answer in the documentation/on here but no luck so far.

I've been trying to display a pandas dataframe in a QTableView, which is working fine now. I want to add a column containing checkboxes which will ultimately determine what happens with an entire row. I have subclassed QStyledItemDelegate like this:

```
class CheckBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CheckBoxDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QCheckBox(parent)
        editor.stateChanged.connect(self.commit_editor)
        return editor

    def commit_editor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)
```

Which gives me the behavior I want, but I don't want the delegate to be on top of the original data, which is happening now:

[image]

I'm setting the delegate here:

```
self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, checkbox_delegate)
```

The model is going to be used to propose changes to a database to a user. I want to add a column with just checkboxes so a user can exclude certain rows from being changed. I know I could use `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` but as far as I could find, I can't use that if I want to show just the checkbox (and not the field values). I am aware that it's possible to select rows in other ways, but I don't feel like those are appropriate for my purposes here.

Full code: (this is just a quick experiment, not meant for production as is)

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QVBoxLayout, QDialog, QAbstractItemView, QCheckBox, QStyledItemDelegate
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QAbstractTableModel, QVariant, QModelIndex, QSortFilterProxyModel

class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super(PandasModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = df
        self.num_rows, self.num_columns = self._data.shape

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.num_columns

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.num_rows

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            # print('setting')
            return QVariant('{}'.format(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))
        else:
            return QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return flags

    def sort(self, Ncol, order):
        """Sort table by given column number.
        """
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._data = self._data.sort_values(self._data.columns[Ncol], ascending=not order)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        self.dataChanged.emit(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex())

class CheckBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CheckBoxDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QCheckBox(parent)
        editor.stateChanged.connect(self.commit_editor)
        return editor

    def commit_editor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)

class PandasWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, df, selectable_rows=True):
        super(PandasWidget, self).__init__()
        self._df = df
        if selectable_rows:
            self._df.insert(0, 'Include row', True)
        self.table = QTableView()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        model = PandasModel(self._df)
        proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)
        self.table.setModel(proxy_model)
        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        checkbox_delegate = CheckBoxDelegate(self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, checkbox_delegate)
        for i in range(self.table.model().rowCount(self.table.rootIndex())):
            self.table.openPersistentEditor(self.table.model().index(i, 0, self.table.rootIndex()))
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = {
        'Col X': list('ABCD'),
        'col Y': [10, 20, 30, 40]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    demo = PandasWidget(df)
    demo.exec_()
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your model? Also explain how the checkbox should behave: should the user be able to interact, or is it only for display purposes?

Comment: Btw, opening a delegate inside `paint()` is certainly not a good practice: in a painting function only painting operations should happen.

Comment: Instead of using a item delegate to add check boxes you could add the flag `Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable` to the item flags of the items in the first column. How this is done depends on how you are managing the items in your table.

Comment: @musicamante I've updated my question, hope it's a little more clear now. I'm aware that it isn't good practice to open a delegate in ```paint()```, this is just an experimental version, but I've changed it regardless. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a different model that stores the states of the checkBox and concatenate it to the initial model:

```py
import sys
import pandas as pd

from PyQt5.QtCore import (
    Qt,
    QAbstractTableModel,
    QVariant,
    QModelIndex,
    QSortFilterProxyModel,
    QTransposeProxyModel,
    QConcatenateTablesProxyModel,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QTableView,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QDialog,
    QAbstractItemView,
    QHeaderView,
)


class PandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, df):
        super(PandasModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = df
        self.num_rows, self.num_columns = self._data.shape

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.num_columns

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self.num_rows

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            # print('setting')
            return QVariant("{}".format(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]))
        else:
            return QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return QVariant()

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return flags

    def sort(self, Ncol, order):
        """Sort table by given column number."""
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._data = self._data.sort_values(
            self._data.columns[Ncol], ascending=not order
        )
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        self.dataChanged.emit(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex())


class PandasWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, df, selectable_rows=True):
        super(PandasWidget, self).__init__()
        self._df = df
        if selectable_rows:
            self._df.insert(0, "Include row", True)
        self.table = QTableView()

        model = PandasModel(self._df)

        checkmodel = QStandardItemModel(0, model.columnCount())
        items = []
        for i in range(model.columnCount()):
            it = QStandardItem()
            it.setCheckable(True)
            items.append(it)
        checkmodel.appendRow(items)

        transpose_model = QTransposeProxyModel()
        transpose_model.setSourceModel(model)

        concatenate_model = QConcatenateTablesProxyModel()
        concatenate_model.addSourceModel(checkmodel)
        concatenate_model.addSourceModel(transpose_model)

        transpose_model_2 = QTransposeProxyModel()
        transpose_model_2.setSourceModel(concatenate_model)

        proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(transpose_model_2)
        self.table.setModel(proxy_model)

        self.table.setSelectionBehavior(QTableView.SelectRows)
        self.table.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents
        )

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    data = {"Col X": list("ABCD"), "col Y": [10, 20, 30, 40]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    demo = PandasWidget(df)
    demo.exec_()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to display a checkbox in an item view it's not necessary to use a delegate, but to correctly return a [CheckState](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#CheckState-enum) value when the `CheckStateRole` is used for `data()`:

```
    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.column() == 0:
            # this if block automatically avoids returning values for the display
            # role on the first column
            if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
                value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
                return Qt.Checked if value else Qt.Unchecked
        elif role in (Qt.DisplayRole, Qt.EditRole):
            # print('setting')
            return self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
```

<sup>Note: it's not required to return QVariant(), as PyQt automatically converts python objects to values suitable for Qt.</sup>

If interaction is required for the checkbox, then both `flags()` and `setData()` must be properly implemented:

```
    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return False
        if role == Qt.CheckStateRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = bool(value)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        elif role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

    def flags(self, index):
        flags = super().flags(index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            flags |= Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
        else:
            flags |= Qt.ItemIsEditable
        return flags
```

Some slightly unrelated considerations about your usage of the delegate:

- as already reported in the comments, painting functions should only do painting operations; luckily, `openPersistentEditor()` is smart enough to do nothing if an editor already exists, but nonetheless it's good practice to avoid any operation that would involve changes in the "layout" of a widget, as it can potentially lead to infinite recursion;
- `self.sender()` should be avoid when possible; in your case you could have just used a lambda: `editor.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.commitData.emit(editor))`;
- you didn't use the signal argument, so it's not an issue, but be aware that `stateChanged` emits a *CheckState*, not a boolean (so `Checked` is actually 2, and that's why I used `bool(value)` in `setData()`); it's usually better to use `toggle` instead;